# Mininet, Openvswitch, CLI or SNMP

Tags: snmp, mininet, openvswitch

I'm building a virtual environment and need to simulate a real switch with devices attached.  I prefer to stay away from a single vendor solution & Mininet/OVS look promising.

However, I don't find snmp support in the docs.  I need to obtain the switch arp & mac tables (at a minimum) via either SNMP or a cli command via ssh.  This is trivial with a Cisco switch or most any hardware vendor.

Any thoughts in how I can simulate this with mininet?

TIA,

-Steve

Answer (score 0):

ovs switches are openflow switches, openflow switches maintain flow tables.

Do you need to simulate or emulate?
checkout GNS3

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is a protocol of the management plane, not of the data or control plane which is the focus of SDN.

However, I think I read about an ODL (OpenDaylight) project that offers a controller app/plugin to handle SNMP. [This](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/SNMP_Plugin:Main) might be it.

ODL & OVS & Mininet work together.